# Not Adding to Array Properly. Hope for assistance

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I am using BlueJ, for reference.

The program compiles and runs fine.

The problem is that I believe I am supposed to be adding to an existing array, but instead it seems I'm just adding to a new one.

The program reads this text file called "EmployeeData.TXT":

```
S       Washington,George       000001      125000
H   MacDonald,Ronald        386218     7.80 true  40
H       Walton,Samuel           268517  8.21    false
H   Thomas,David            131313  9.45    true    38
H   Sanders,HarlandDavid    277651  8.72    false
S   Baron,James         368535  310236
```

I am supposed to be adding (among other things) to that.

When I add an employee, it doesn't display it with the above list of employees, it doesn't display that list at all.

Here is a snippet of the output I currently get, showing it doesn't include the text file data.

```
S, Ghandhi, Mohandas 1111 150000.0
H, Luther, Maritn 2222 10.5 false false
H, Mandela, Nelson 3333 12.5 true true 40
```

In addition, I'm not sure why there is a comma coming after the S / H.. Is that what causes it to not add to the data brought from the text file?

Here is my main class, `WorkerApp`:

```
public class WorkerApp{ 
    public static void  main (String args[]){
        Company company = new Company();
        try{
            Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File("EmployeeData.txt"));
            while(reader.hasNext()){
                String line = reader.nextLine();
                String Employee[] = new String[7];
                String sorh = Employee[0];
                String name = Employee[1];
                String id = Employee[2];
                double salary = Double.parseDouble(Employee[3]);
                Employee e;
                if (Employee[0].equals("S")){
                    e = new SalariedWorker(sorh, name, id, salary);}
                else {
                    boolean overtime = Boolean.parseBoolean(Employee[4]);
                    if(overtime){
                        int maxhu = Integer.parseInt(Employee[5]);
                        e = new HourlyWorker(sorh, name, id, salary, maxhu);
                    }
                    else{
                        e = new HourlyWorker(sorh, name, id, salary);
                    }
                }
                company.add(e);
            }
       }catch (Exception err){
           System.out.println("Cannot open EmployeeData.TXT.");
       }   

       System.out.println("REPORT");
       company.print();
       System.out.println();

       System.out.println("1. Adding a salaried worker");
       SalariedWorker s1 = new SalariedWorker("S", "Ghandhi, Mohandas", "1111", 150000);
       company.add(s1);
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("this will trigger the expand capacity method");
       HourlyWorker h1 = new HourlyWorker("H", "Luther, Maritn", "2222", 10.5);
       company.add(h1);
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("3, Adding an hourly worker who has overtime allowed.");
       HourlyWorker h2 = new HourlyWorker("H", "Mandela, Nelson", "3333", 12.5, 40);
       company.add(h2);
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("4. Adding a worker that is already in the database");

       try{
           company.add(s1);
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
           System.out.println();
       }

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("5. Printing the sorted list.");
       company.print();
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("6,. Removing a worker who is Not in the list.");

       SalariedWorker s2 = new SalariedWorker("S", "Parks, Rosa", "5555", 11600);
       company.remove("abc");
       System.out.println();

       System.out.println("7. Removing a worker who is the first in the list");
       company.remove("Baron, James");
       System.out.println();

       System.out.println("8. Finding a worker who is the middle of the list.");
       int index = company.find("Newton, Isaac");
       System.out.println("Found at "+index);
       System.out.println();

        System.out.println("9. Finding a worker who is not in the list.");
        index = company.find("xyz, abc");
        System.out.println("Found at "+index);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("10. Finding the weekly salary of a worker who is salaried");
        System.out.println(s1.FindSalary());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("11. FInd the weekly Salary of an hourly worker who has no overtime allowed.");
        System.out.println("[Entering a time of 50 hours]");
        System.out.println(h1.FindSalary(50));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("12, FInd the weekly Salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed.");
        System.out.println("[Entering the time of 50 hours]");
        System.out.println(h2.FindSalary(50));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("13. FInd the weekly Salary of an hourly worker who has overtime allowed.");
        System.out.println("[Entering a time of 20 hours]");
        System.out.println(h2.FindSalary(20));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("14. Printing the sorted list.");
        company.print();
    } 
}
```

Perhaps my problem lies in my Company class?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Company{
    private Employee[] employeeArray;
    private final int InitialCapacity = 7;
    private int employCount;

    public Company(){
        employeeArray = new Employee[InitialCapacity];
        employCount = 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return employCount;
    } 

    public int find(String name){
        for (int i = 0; i < employCount; i++){
            if (employeeArray[i].getName().equals(name)){
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public int add(Employee employ){
        int index;

        for (index = 0; index < employCount; index++){
            int result = employeeArray[index].getName().compareTo(employ.getName());
            if(result == 0){
                throw new RuntimeException ("Employee Not New");
            }
        }

        if (employeeArray.length == employCount){
            expand();
        }

        for(int i = employCount; i > index; i--){
            employeeArray[i] = employeeArray[i - 1];
        }

        employeeArray[index] = employ;
        employCount++;
        return index;
    }

    public void remove(String name){
        int index = find(name);
        if (index == -1){
            System.out.println("Employee not Found");
            return;
        }

        for (int i = index; i < employCount - 1; i++){
            employeeArray[i] = employeeArray[i + 1];
        }

        employCount--;
    }

    public void print(){
        if(employCount == 0){
            System.out.println("List is Empty");
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < employCount; i++){
            System.out.println(employeeArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public Object get(int index){
        if(index >= 0 && index < employCount){
            return employeeArray[index];
        }else{
            return "List out of Bounds";
        }
    } 

    private void expand(){
        Employee[] newArray = new Employee[employeeArray.length + InitialCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++){
            newArray[i] = employeeArray[i];
        }
        employeeArray = newArray;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insertion logic seems strange. If you wish to add a new employee at the end of the array (meaning at the first unoccupied spot in the array), you don't need the second loop.

All you need is to check that the Employee is not already in the array (your first loop), and then add the employee at the `index` position (which would be identical to `employCount`).

```
public int add(Employee employ)
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < employCount; index++){
        int result = employeeArray[index].getName().compareTo(employ.getName());
        if(result == 0){
            throw new RuntimeException ("Employee Not New");
        }
    }

    if (employeeArray.length == employCount){
        expand();
    }

    employeeArray[index] = employ;
    employCount++;
    return index;
}
```

EDIT :

You have a much larger problem than what I mentioned above :

```
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            String Employee[] = new String[7];
```

You have a line from the file, but do nothing with it. Then you create a String array and start to access its values, even though they are all null. Therefore, method calls such as `Employee[0].equals("S")` would cause a `NullPointerException`.

What you should do is :

```
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            String Employee[] = line.split(" "); // assuming " " is the separator 
                                                 // between tokens in each line
```

Now your `Employee` array (which you should rally call employee, if you don't want to confuse it with the `Employee` class) would contain the columns of the line and you can access them in the remainder of your loop.

Comment: After implementing this code, nothing has changed, unfortunately. Still not outputting the text file along with the added employees, it's still /just/ showing the added employees.